# Using abstract generic classes in software design factory pattern

Tags: vb.net, generics, abstract-class, factory-pattern

I have a bit of a design issue. I created a rate calculator as follows :

```
Public Interface ICalculator
 Property PaymentTerm As Double
 Function Calculate() As CommissionValues
 ReadOnly Property CalculationRule As CalculationRuleEnum
End Interface

Public Interface IFlexibleRateCalculator
 Inherits ICalculator
  Property TransferRate As Decimal
End Interface

Public Interface IFixedRateCalculator
 Inherits ICalculator
  Property ContractRate As Decimal
End Interface

Public Interface IRateSettingBase
  Property RateType As RateTypeEnum
  ReadOnly Property Calculator As ICalculator
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class RateSetting
 Implements IRateSettingBase
  Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Calculator() As ICalculator Implements IRateSettingBase.Calculator
```

I can do something like this:

```
dim ratevalues as RateValues = RateSetting().Calculator.Calculate()
```

Pretty simple. The problem is that each type of calculator has their own set of properties that need to be set in order for their Calculate() methods to work properly.
So I end up having to  implement as follows

```
FlexibleRateCalculator
Implements IFlexibleRateCalculator
    Private mRequestedRate As Decimal
    Public Function Calculate() As RateValues Implements ICalculator.Calculate
    
FixedRateCalculator
 Implements IFixedRateCalculator
    Private mTransferRate As Decimal
    Public Function Calculate() As RateValues Implements ICalculator.Calculate
```

What is the best way using generics and abstract classes to create a factory pattern that will generate a calculator of a specific type dynamically??

I need a very generic solution as many calculation rates will be added and modified all with their own parameters needed for the calculation logic. I want to be able to do this quickly and possibly control these rate calculation via db. FYI answers in C# or VB.Net are welcome :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this vb.net? Please add a language tag to get more attention.

Comment: Thanks. And yes its in VB.Net right now but I may be converting to C# so either syntax would help. I'm more concerned with the design. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep only the `ICalculator` interface and convert the more specific interfaces to classes. I can't think of a good reason why you would create a class just to store a variable, so I'm going to get rid of the `RateSetting` entirely.

```
Public Interface ICalculator
    Property Rate As Double
    Property PaymentTerm As Double
    Function Calculate() As CommissionValues
    ReadOnly Property CalculationRule As CalculationRuleEnum
End Interface

Public Class FlexibleRateCalculator : Implements ICalculator

    Public Sub New(rate As Double)
        Me.Rate = rate
    End Sub

    '
    ' ICalculator implementation goes here
    '

End Class

Public Class FixedRateCalculator : Implements ICalculator

    Public Sub New(rate As Double)
        Me.Rate = rate
    End Sub

    '
    ' ICalculator implementation goes here
    '

End Class

Public Enum RateType
    Flexible = 1
    Fixed = 2
End Enum

Public Class CalculatorFactory

    Public Shared Function GetCalculator(rate As Double, type As RateType) As ICalculator
        Select Case type
            Case RateType.Flexible
                Return New FlexibleRateCalculator(rate)
            Case RateType.Fixed
                Return New FixedRateCalculator(rate)
            Case Else
                Throw New ArgumentException
        End Select
    End Function

End Class
```

You create object instances by passing a rate and a rate type to the `GetCalculator` method. I don't know what you mean by `CalculationRule`, but if it's important to the end user then you should add it as an additional parameter.

You can easily add more calculator types that implement ICalculator, as long as you don't forget to update the select statement in the factory method.

EDIT: of course you can also set additional properties before returning an object instance. The point of this pattern however is to make sure that the end-user does not need to know about how `Calculate()` is implemented. If you want to make more specific factory methods for every calculator, it kind of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with any IoC containers? You should be able use the factory-type services they provide to generate you the appropriate types with appropriate parameters/properties based on a given type (enum, string, etc.)

If not, you could probably create a factory class that has a method that generates the appropriate type based on a parameter. This method could accept a ParamArray or other object that contains the properties needed to correctly set-up the calculator and then return it, via the ICalculator interface.